# What exactly are "Voluntary context switches"?

Tags: command-line, process, cpu

I got a binary file and I'm supposed to crack its password (homework). There was also a function given (a function which is a part of the binary file). That function showed that the input string was compared with the correct password character by character and returned false instantly when a character was wrong (that's not secure way of doing it I guess because it's leaking time and we get an idea of the correct password length as example). But our teacher has added a random timer that returns the result (Correct / Wrong) to make it a little harder for us...

Anyway, I have I already done it successfully with reverse engineering and got the correct password. Now I'm playing with it in the command line:

```
/usr/bin/time -v ./program_name enter_password
```

With this command, I get a lot information such as system time, swaps, execution time..But what is most interesting to me is "Voluntary context switches" because the more correct characters of the password I enter, the less "Voluntary context switches" I get!

The more wrong characters I enter, the more "Voluntary context switches" I get.

It took me almost two hours to crack the password just by entering that command, entering characters and observing "Voluntary context switches". Whenever ONE character was correct, the "Voluntary context switches" decreased by one.

**My question, what exactly are "Voluntary context switches" and why did they help me cracking the password?**

Comment: Congratulations on discovering for yourself the rich and still not fully understood field of [side-channel attacks](http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/c653/lectures/SideC/intro.pdf).

Comment: @zwol What do you mean by "rich"? And besides, we are currently dealing with side-channel attacks in class, excuse me that I don't have "fully understood" its field that quickly....

Comment: @cnmesr I took it as a sincere comment, not a sarcastic one, saying that zwol considers the field an interesting one since new discoveries are still being made. It's not that *you* haven't fully understood it, it's that *no one* fully understands it, and that's what makes it interesting.

Comment: @hvd cnmesr Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @zwol Oh sorry then! I misinterpreted you and saw it as an attack :p

Comment: Very interesting question. I'm a newbie in this but I have just written a little program that looks quite similar to your description that asks for a password and I was indeed able to find the password by going character by character and looking at the changes of Voluntary context switches.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The [man page for `time`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) explains the concept of voluntary and involuntary context switches:

```
The resource specifiers [...] are:
   c      Number of times the process was context-switched involuntarily
          (because the time slice expired).
   w      Number of times that the program was context-switched voluntarily, 
          for instance while waiting for an I/O operation to complete.
```

<sub>(quote is from my Debian system, the linked man page has a slightly different text)</sub>

That is, a context switch is voluntary, if the process leaves the CPU because it has nothing else to do (while waiting for something external to happen). Involuntary, if it would like to continue some computation, but the OS decides it's time to switch to some other process.

---

How any of this is related to the password-checking program, depends on what the program actually does.

From the source code linked in the comments, we see that the program calls `usleep()` once for each non-matching character, continuing the comparison loop on the next character afterwards. Sleeping is about as voluntary as yielding the CPU ever gets, so these calls will show as voluntary context switches for each non-maching character.

On Linux, you should be able to see the calls with `strace`, too.

The final delay comes from a randomized sleep of `T * (rand() % 3)`, i.e. 0, 1, or 2 times a constant. That's a rather coarse granularity, so it should be easy to average out by doing multiple attempts with the same password.

Comment: Here is the source code of the function I mentioned above https://pastebin.com/iTzheD4u Thank you I will take a look at the calls with strace and hopefully get some more information. About the random timer: If the password has a wrong length, the output time is the same (very very fast) and the random timer doesn't get executed. If the password length is correct, the output is random because random timer is executed.

Comment: @cnmesr, oh, that's excellent!